# How do I get whole and fractional parts from double in JSP/Java?

Tags: java, math, jsp

How do I get whole and fractional parts from double in JSP/Java ? If the value is 3.25 then I want to get `fractional =.25`, `whole = 3`

How can we do this in Java?

Comment: You seem to have an inaccurate idea of what mantissa and exponent are. They aren't just "whole part" and "fractional part". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Keep the original title otherwise most of the answers don't make sense.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Obtainingtheintegerandfractionalparts.htm

```
double num;
long iPart;
double fPart;

// Get user input
num = 2.3d;
iPart = (long) num;
fPart = num - iPart;
System.out.println("Integer part = " + iPart);
System.out.println("Fractional part = " + fPart);
```

Outputs:

```
Integer part = 2
Fractional part = 0.2999999999999998
```

Comment: Actually this page is the first hit on a google search for "get fractional and whole part out from double java" =)

Comment: Actually this answer is incorrect, for values larger than long can represent it will give huge numbers in the fractional part. Dan Vinton answer below is just as simple and always returns the correct result.

Comment: so actually, this is not correct, as you can see in the output. the input is fraction of 3 and output is 29999999...using BigDecimal instead of Double will do the trick though

Comment: 0.2999999999999 is equal to 0.3

Comment: @Alex No, the input is a number which is very close to `2.3`, but surely not `2.3`. And there's nothing wrong with the output, unless you want much more than 10 valid digits. All you need is some rounding in each output (e.g., format `%.9f`) which is usually less pain than `BigDecimal`. The only problem here is the overflow.

Comment: Converting double to int is almost always a bad idea. Because e.g. for `(long)1.0e100` you will get 0. A lot of the times you need the double value simply "floored" for which there is `floor()`. If you want both integral and fraction parts use `modf()`. Really, this is a bad answer.

Comment: @mojuba there is no `modf()` in Java

Answer (score 171):

```
double value = 3.25;
double fractionalPart = value % 1;
double integralPart = value - fractionalPart;
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Works fine, and with my edit will work with negative values as well.

Comment: The integer part could be => long longPart = (long)3.25

Comment: Won't work for neg. values. I.e. -3.25 % 1 = 0.75 not 0.25. So integralPart will be -3.25 - 0.75 = -4.

Comment: @WindRider, I checked for negative.. and its works.. however for decimal places which are small in number, there will be a slight error. Ex. for -03.0025 it returns -0.0024999999999999467 and -3.0

Comment: The confusion here is because some languages, such as Python, use `%` to mean modulo (`-3.25 % 1 == 0.75`) and others, such as Java, Fortran, C, and C++, use `%` to mean remainder (`-3.25 % 1 == -0.25`).  WindRider may have typed it into a Python REPL for expediency, but that answer is misleading because this question is about the JVM.

Answer (score 25):

Use [JSTL](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/tagdocs/) ([installation instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/4928309#4928309)) [fmt](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/tagdocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) taglib. There's a [`<fmt:formatNumber>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) tag which does exactly what you want and in a quite easy manner with help of `maxFractionDigits` and `maxIntegerDigits` attributes.

Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%
    // Just for quick prototyping. Don't do this in real! Use servlet/javabean.
    double d = 3.25;
    request.setAttribute("d", d);
%>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 343584</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Whole: <fmt:formatNumber value="${d}" maxFractionDigits="0" />
        <p>Fraction: <fmt:formatNumber value="${d}" maxIntegerDigits="0" />
    </body>
</html>
```

<sub>*(NOTE: if you're not on JSTL 3.0+ yet, use `uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"` instead)*</sub>

Output:

> Whole: 3
>
> Fraction: .25

That's it. No need to massage it with help of plain Java code.

Answer (score 8):

The original question asked for the exponent and mantissa, rather than the fractional and whole part.

To get the exponent and mantissa from a double you can convert it into the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation and extract the bits like this:

```
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(3.25);

boolean isNegative = (bits & 0x8000000000000000L) != 0; 
long exponent      = (bits & 0x7ff0000000000000L) >> 52;
long mantissa      =  bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL;
```

Comment: Isn't the first bit of the mantinssa implicitly set to 1, so the mantissa should be (bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL) | 0x0010000000000000L?

Comment: Rasmus it wasnt a ryt output
Output: exponent 0  and  mantissa 2814749767106560

and if u choose urs agnul the mantissa is 0

Comment: Broken with 4 up votes:) Although I see what the code is trying to do with taking apart double value at its joints, the code doesn't seem to output the right values.

Comment: @agnul: I think "mantissa" usually refers to just the value of the bits. You might just convert this to the significand by (sometimes) prepending a 1 bit. But according to Wikipedia, the word mantissa is now deprecated in favor of "fraction".

Answer (score 5):

The mantissa and exponent of an IEEE double floating point number are the values such that

```
value = sign * (1 + mantissa) * pow(2, exponent)
```

if the mantissa is of the form 0.101010101_base 2 (ie its most sigificant bit is shifted to be after the binary point) and the exponent is adjusted for bias.

Since 1.6, java.lang.Math also provides a direct method to get the unbiased exponent (called getExponent(double))

However, the numbers you're asking for are the integral and fractional parts of the number, which can be obtained using

```
integral = Math.floor(x)
fractional = x - Math.floor(x)
```

though you may you want to treat negative numbers differently `(floor(-3.5) == -4.0)`, depending why you want the two parts.

I'd strongly suggest that you don't call these mantissa and exponent.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this is faster but I'm using

```
float fp = ip % 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 4):

Main logic you have to first find how many digits are there after the decimal point.
 This code works for any number upto 16 digits. If you use BigDecimal you can run it just for upto 18 digits. put the input value (your number) to the variable "num", here as an example i have hard coded it.

```
double num, temp=0;
double frac,j=1;

num=1034.235;
// FOR THE FRACTION PART
do{
j=j*10;
temp= num*j;
}while((temp%10)!=0);       

j=j/10;
temp=(int)num;
frac=(num*j)-(temp*j);

System.out.println("Double number= "+num);      
System.out.println("Whole part= "+(int)num+" fraction part= "+(int)frac);
```

Comment: Now the person that did the down-vote (not me btw), should have explained _why_ there was a down-vote.  That's not good.  But all of us had a score of 1 at some point or other.

Comment: @Gray the question was to separate 3.25 as '3' and '25', and the accepted answer will never ever give '25', it will always give '2599999999'

Comment: This anwer is very useful if you want the fractional part as an integer

Answer (score 3):

*[Edit: The question originally asked how to get the mantissa and exponent.]*

Where *n* is the number to get the real mantissa/exponent:

```
exponent = int(log(n))
mantissa = n / 10^exponent
```

Or, to get the answer you were looking for:

```
exponent = int(n)
mantissa = n - exponent
```

These are not Java exactly but should be easy to convert.

Answer (score 1):

What if your number is 2.39999999999999. I suppose you want to get the exact decimal value. Then use BigDecimal:

```
Integer x,y,intPart;
BigDecimal bd,bdInt,bdDec;
bd = new BigDecimal("2.39999999999999");
intPart = bd.intValue();
bdInt = new BigDecimal(intPart);
bdDec = bd.subtract(bdInt);
System.out.println("Number : " + bd);
System.out.println("Whole number part : " + bdInt);
System.out.println("Decimal number part : " + bdDec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `fmt:formatNumber` tag doesn't always yield the correct result, here is another JSP-only approach: It just formats the number as string and does the rest of the computation on the string, since that is easier and doesn't involve further floating point arithmetics.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<%
  double[] numbers = { 0.0, 3.25, 3.75, 3.5, 2.5, -1.5, -2.5 };
  pageContext.setAttribute("numbers", numbers);
%>

<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <c:forEach var="n" items="${numbers}">
        <li>${n} = ${fn:substringBefore(n, ".")} + ${n - fn:substringBefore(n, ".")}</li>
      </c:forEach>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just try all the numbers from my example. `fmt:formatNumber` rounds its argument, which is not wanted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers have horrid rounding errors because they're casting numbers from one type to another.  How about:

```
double x=123.456;
double fractionalPart = x-Math.floor(x);
double wholePart = Math.floor(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer don't work well for negative numbers between -0 and -1.0
Also give the fractional part negative.

For example: 
For number -0,35

returns

Integer part = 0
Fractional part = -0.35

If wou are working with GPS coordinates it is better to have a result with the signum on the integer part as:

Integer part = -0 
Fractional part = 0.35

Theses  numbers are used for example for GPS coordinates, where are important the signum for Lat or Long position

Propose code:

```
    double num;
    double iPart;
    double fPart;

    // Get user input
    num = -0.35d;
    iPart = (long) num;
    //Correct numbers between -0.0 and -1.0
    iPart = (num<=-0.0000001 && num>-1.0)? -iPart : iPart ;
    fPart = Math.abs(num - iPart);
    System.out.println(String.format("Integer part = %01.0f",iPart));
    System.out.println(String.format("Fractional part = %01.04f",fPart));
```

Output:

```
Integer part = -0
Fractional part = 0,3500
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, you can use `Math.floorDiv`.

It returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) `int` value that is less than or equal to the algebraic quotient.

Some examples:

```
floorDiv(4, 3) == 1
floorDiv(-4, 3) == -2
```

Alternatively, the `/` operator can be used:

```
(4 / 3) == 1
(-4 / 3) == -1
```

References:

- [Java 8 : Math.floorDiv(int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-)
- [Java 8 : Math.floorDiv(long,long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-long-long-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use BigDecimal for the solution. Like this:

```
    double value = 3.25;
    BigDecimal wholeValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(value).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
    double fractionalValue = value - wholeValue.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "3.06";

if(!value.isEmpty()){
    if(value.contains(".")){    
        String block = value.substring(0,value.indexOf("."));
        System.out.println(block);
    }else{
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
// target float point number
double d = 3.025;

// transfer the number to string
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
String format = df.format(d);

// split the number into two fragments
int dotIndex = format.indexOf(".");
int iPart = Integer.parseInt(format.substring(0, dotIndex)); // output: 3
double fPart = Double.parseDouble(format.substring(dotIndex)); // output: 0.025
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is maybe late, but i think the best and more accurate approach is using BigDecimal

```
double d = 11.38;

BigDecimal bigD = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
int intPart = bigD.intValue();
double fractionalPart = bigD.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(intPart)).doubleValue();

System.out.println(intPart); // 11
System.out.println(fractionalPart ); //0.38
```

Comment: If you have a double, it has float imprecision. Converting it to a BigDecimal will not magically restore its precision.

Comment: @Taschi i think the question is about separating the int and the fractional part, not about restore its precision!

Comment: Omar, you specifically talked about your approach being "more accurate", which I think is just not true. Your answer is entirely acceptable but that wording seems misleading to me, which is why I commented on it.

Comment: @Taschi, i said that because in many answers you lose value when you get the output, e.g. `input (5.03)` `output int = 5 , fractional = 0.0299999` , we are talking about inputs and outputs, u put value and get back your value without losing 0.001% of it! and this accurate, not misleading!

Comment: yes. You lose precision when you store something as a double in the first place. Rounding when converting to a BigDecimal also loses precision. Those two losses of precision may cancel each other out, but that does not "restore" precision, because restoring precision is mathematically impossible. You cannot pull information out of thin air.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MyMain2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myDub;
        myDub=1234.5678;
        long myLong;
        myLong=(int)myDub;
        myDub=(myDub%1)*10000;
        int myInt=(int)myDub;
        System.out.println(myLong + "\n" + myInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if the number has exactly 4 decimal places. Not otherwise.