# Separating double into integer and decimal parts

Tags: java, math

I am trying to separate a double into the integer and decimal parts

So for example, the number 24.4 should be separated into 24 and 4.

```
int integer = (int)number;
double decimal = number-(int)number;
System.out.println(decimal);
```

Using this method gives me the following values :

```
integer = 24
decimal = 0.3999999999999986
```

I need the value of decimal to be 4.

How can this problem be fixed ?

Comment: You can format it to print just 1 digit after decimal.

Comment: Do you understand that the number 24.4 can't be exactly represented as a `double`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get whole and fractional parts from double in jsp/java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343584/how-do-i-get-whole-and-fractional-parts-from-double-in-jsp-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a String [`split(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). And then Integer [`parseInt(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to get back the two integer components.

Comment: This is dangerous: 2.03 will be processed as decimal part "3" instead of "03".

Comment: @PacoAbato, OP requested the decimal value in integer instead of string.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `double`s aren't exactly "real numbers" - remember there are infinite number of real numbers in any range, while there are only finite number of digits in `double` - thus finite number of values, so some round off must occure.

The fact is, 24.4 cannot be exactly represented by `double` - so the fraction of your number really is something around 0.3999....

If you want an exact solution - you should use a library that gives you exact values for decimals, such as [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

If you want to understand more about this issue of `double`s being not exact - you should read more about [floating points arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), and [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), though high level, is also a must in order to really understand what's going on.

If you cannot understand these article just yet - just take into consideration: If you need an exact value - `double`s cannot provide it - and you should use a library if this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the number of decimal digits, you could use this method:

```
double number = 24.4;

int integer = (int)number;
double decimal = (10 * number - 10 * integer)/10;

System.out.println(decimal);
```

**Explanation**: Remove the decimal points, do the subtraction, and finally return the decimal point back to its original location!

Comment: This technique fails in over 90% of cases.

Comment: @EJP *Depending on the number of decimal digits!* Please show me one failing case when there is only one decimal digit.

Comment: There is no exact representation for 0.1. How can it possibly work? Try it for 24.1 through 24.9.

Comment: It works for all your numbers. Please also see the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

```
float number = (float) 22.45;
int integer = (int)number;
double decimal = number-integer;
System.out.println(integer + "decimal" + decimal);
```

Comment: Hi user3291532 -- while posting an answer like this can be helpful, it's better to leave some explanation about why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small method I wrote to accomplish this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param n
 * @return 
 */
private static double getFractionalPart(double n) {     
    if (n > 0) {
        return n - Math.floor(n);
    } else {
        return ((n - Math.ceil(n)) * -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution: I used a simple method in C to split the Fractional Numbers into two Different Integers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
float x=24.56; int y=(int)x; float z=(x-y)*1000000000; int zd=(int)z;
printf("%lf",x);
printf("\ninteger Part %d\n",y);
printf("\nDecimal Part %d\n",zd);
}
```

Output

---

```
24.559999
integer Part 24

Decimal Part 559999488
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the way with little workaround and I am sure it works for all the cases.

The code says it all.

```
        double number = input.nextDouble(); // 234.025
        String s = Double.toString(number); // "234.025"
        s = "0" + s.substring(s.indexOf(".")); //"0.025"
        double decimal = Double.parseDouble(s);// 0.025
        int num = (int)number; // 234
        System.out.println(decimal + " " + num); //0.025 234
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the number the digits after the decimal point, and with that much number of 10's you have to multiply. eg: x=26.78621 then multiply by 100000[ here you can't multiply like x*10, again x*10 so on (5 times), the 1st time you multiply with 10, it will give you 267.862199999..] After multiplication subtract 2600000 from the result. here is a link of your answer which i have code it.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517555/2508414

Answer (score 0):

As RGO stated, you can do that and also round the decimal number in order to get the appropriate  value.
Ex:

```
double number = 20.57;

int integer = (int)number;
double decimal = (10 * number - 10 * integer)/10;
double temp =  Math.round(decimal*100.0)/100.0;
System.out.println("Int = " + integer + "\nDecimal = " + temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
(val - val.longValue()) * 100
```

use 1000 to get 3 fractions:

for example:

```
(1.2445 - 1) * 100 = 0.244
```