# Changing the values from EditText programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a decimal number in EditText and I'm trying to change it to always show a decimal part but the user doesn't be able to change the decimal part, only the integer part has to be editable. The decimal part is always a default value.

Example: I have the number 2.025,50 at EditText, if I delete all the digits I`ll have 0,50. If I write 10 , I`ll have 10,50.

Can anyone help me out ??

Comment: It will be very useful if u post code of what you have tried.

Comment: that means .50 will be default value that will always be available on edit text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating double into integer and decimal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044079/separating-double-into-integer-and-decimal-parts)

Comment: yes @AbdulWaheed. @kudzi isn`t duplicated because it happening at EditText, what means the user always has to see the correct value while he write.

Comment: I have updated my answer tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function you can use for this, so you just input your number with a decimal and it will give you the decimal part of the number. Use editText changed listener. So when u pass the value being typed by a user call this function and pass the numberWithTheFraction to the function getFractionalPart and add the userinput as shown in the code bellow.

```
   private static double getFractionalPart(double num) {     
       if (num > 0) {
          return num - Math.floor(num);
       } else {
          return ((num - Math.ceil(num)) * -1);
}
}
```

you can have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ_32Tuuu74) example for an example of editText change listener.

So in the above example when you say `textView.setText(getFractionalPart(numberWithTheFraction)+userInput)`

Comment: It helped with the fractional part, but how can I block the user to not change this part in EditText?

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean block the user because the word this is ambiguous in your question.