# How to get decimal parts in integer from double?

Tags: java, math, decimal, decimal-point

How to separate double into two integer number? First number before and second number after decimal point.
For example:

```
            double doub = 543.345671;
            int num1 = (int) doub; //543
            int num2 = getNumAfterDecimal(doub-num1); //return 345671
```

I need decimal part to integer.

Comment: Do you always want 6 digits after decimal point?

Comment: What do you mean with ` second number after decimal point` ? How many digits do you want? A `double` number has not a fixed precission...

Comment: 6 digits after decimal point are enough for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating double into integer and decimal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044079/separating-double-into-integer-and-decimal-parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how many digits you want after the decimal point, but this is the gist:

```
double d = doub - (int)doub; // will give you 0.xyz
int result = d * 1000; // this is for 3 digits, the number of zeros in the multiplier decides the number of digits
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Double.toString()` to map the `double` to a `String` : `Double.toString(doub)` then use `String.split("\\.")` to get the different parts as `String`s. Then, optionally, `Integer.valueOf()` to parse those values as `Integer`s :

```
double doub = 543.345671;
// Here, you want to split the String on character '.'
// As String.split() takes a regex, the dot must be escaped. 
String[] parts = Double.toString(doub).split("\\.");
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
```

Output :

```
543
345671
```

Answer (score 2):

Get it using regex split,

```
double doub = 543.345671;
String data[] = String.valueOf(doub).split("\\.");
System.out.println("Before decimal: " + Integer.parseInt(data[0]) + ", After decimal: " + Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
```

Prints,

```
Before decimal: 543, After decimal: 345671
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see,

```
Double d=543.345671;
String line=String.valueOf(d);
String[] n=line.split("\\.");
int num1=Integer.parseInt(n[0]);
int num2=Integer.parseInt(n[1]);
```

Comment: It's not bad, but i lose zeros after decimal point. For example: if d=35.0067 i get num2=67 and don't know now many zeros i lost.

Comment: Yes, because int lose leading zeros, If it needs zero at start it shouldn't convert to int and be stayed like string

Answer (score 1):

That's what I need. Thank, **Nir Levy**! But sometimes rounding errors are possible.

```
    double doub = 543.04;
    int num1 = (int) doub; //543
    int num2 = (int) ((doub-num1)*1000000); //39999
```

I added Math.round() to get the decimal part correctly.

```
    double doub = 543.04;
    int num1 = (int) doub; //543
    int num2 = (int) Math.round((doub-num1)*1000000); //40000
```