# How do I format decimal java

Tags: java, custom-component, jformattedtextfield, formatted, custom-formatting

I want to format a decimal number like this:

```
1234.5
   0.5
```

It mean the max number would be 9999.9 (4 characters before ".", 1 character after)

Comment: There's the String.format method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get whole and fractional parts from double in jsp/java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343584/how-do-i-get-whole-and-fractional-parts-from-double-in-jsp-java)

Answer (score 4):

Use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###0.0");
String str = df.format(yourDecimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your result, it may be simpler to use printf

```
for (double d : new double[]{1234.51111, 0.501})
    System.out.printf("%6.1f%n", d);
```

prints

```
1234.5
   0.5
```