# fmod() function for Android

Tags: android

is there any equivalent function for fmod() in android?

--- in c++ : ----

```
double fmod(double x, double y)
float fmodf(float x, float y)
```

The fmod functions compute the floating-point remainder of dividing x by y.

The return value is x - n y, where n is the quotient of x / y, rounded to the first integer towards zero.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but ``Math.IEEEremainder(double x, double y)`` looks pretty close to what you're asking.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/343584/1224741.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus operator, `%`, actually supports both floats and doubles in Java.

And as harism commented, there is the `Math.IEEEremainder(double f1, double f2)` function for doubles if you prefer.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder(double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder%28double,%20double%29)