# How can I split the number 25.15 into 2 different numbers- 25 and 15

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried to split 25.15 into 25 and 15 but it won't work.`

```
double a=n.nextDouble();
int k=(int)(Math.floor(a));
int g=(int)((Math.floor((a-k)*100)));
```

Comment: What types do they have to be ? Doubles too ?

Comment: What type is `n`?

Comment: refer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343584/how-do-i-get-whole-and-fractional-parts-from-double-in-jsp-java)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you want them this way but this should make it:

```
double doubleValue = n.nextDouble();

int integerPart = (int) doubleValue;
int decimalPart = (int) ((doubleValue - integerPart) * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
 String strNum = Double.toString(25.15); //convert Double to String
 String strInt[] = strNum.split(".");   // split the String and store it in array
 Int num1 = Integer.valueOf(strInt[0]);  // convert it to Integer
 Int num2 = Integer.valueOf(strInt[1]);
```

Comment: while this would be dangerous, `02` will be parsed `2`

Comment: @PriyamGupta But he just wants the Integers. In that case he just will have to retain the Strings. With Integer in any case you won't be able to have `02`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but it works.

```
double a = n.nextDouble();
int part1 = Integer.parseInt(new Double(a).toString().split(".")[0]);
int part2 = Integer.parseInt(new Double(a).toString().split(".")[1]);
```