# Extract the value from number after dot in java

Tags: java, int

```
int number = 24.24;

int afterDot = (int) (number*100)%100;
afterDot = 24
```

This logic is wrong if

```
int number1 = 24.4
```

How can I get the 4 from 24.4 ?
Whatever will be the number but want to extract the value after dot.
Actually the formula has to work for both type of value.

Comment: What *is* the value of the number after the dot? Is it 24? 240? 2400? etc.

Comment: `int number = 24.24` does not compile. The literal `24.24` is a `double` and must/should be assigned to a `double` typed variable.

Comment: You could - however - [split a `double` value into its whole and fractional parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343584/how-do-i-get-whole-and-fractional-parts-from-double-in-jsp-java).

Comment: use a double first of all cause the int won't accept the .24

Comment: What should be the result for `1.001`?

Comment: Firstly a Java [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) cannot have a decimal point, assuming you meant a `double` you could do something like this: `int afterDot = Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(number).split("\\.")[1]));`

Comment: Yes @Seelenvirtuose actually its float number =24.4

Comment: @shash678: I suppose the index should be 1, not 0.

Comment: Yah sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your `double` to a string, the problem becomes easier :

```
double number = 24.4;
String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
String decimalPart = numberAsString.split("\\.")[1];
System.out.println(decimalPart);
int number1 = Integer.valueOf(decimalPart); // NOTE: This conversion is lossy.
System.out.println(number1);
```

Note that by converting your `decimalPart` string (e.g. "001") to an integer (`1`), you might lose some information.

With `24.4`, it outputs :

```
4
4
```

With `24.001`, it outputs :

```
001
1
```

With `3d`, it outputs:

```
0
0
```